# Using two different blog listing page templates for the two different blogs in our shop

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Hi we have two blog types defined within our shop and they both use the same template right now.

Specifically I want to make changes to just one of the two blogs listing pages (the page where a summary and thumbnail of each blog article is shown).

How can I achieve this?  Will this automatically happen if I name the templates to something specific a bit like how wordpress handles templating ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

1. in admin/themes click on the three dots and edit the code
2. in the left pane create a new template in the templates directory
3. select blog as template and give it a name, e.g. second_blog
4. this will create a new template file blog.second_blog.json
5. go back to admin: /admin/blogs
6. select the blog to which you want to assign the new template
7. on the bottom right in the theme template dropdown, select the template second_blog
8. In the theme editor select the new template and make the desired changes

You now have two blog templates which you can design individually

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

1. in admin/themes click on the three dots and edit the code
2. in the left pane create a new template in the templates directory
3. select blog as template and give it a name, e.g. second_blog
4. this will create a new template file blog.second_blog.json
5. go back to admin: /admin/blogs
6. select the blog to which you want to assign the new template
7. on the bottom right in the theme template dropdown, select the template second_blog
8. In the theme editor select the new template
   and make the desired changes
9. You now have two blog templates which
   you can design individually

The process is documented [here](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/online-store/themes/theme-structure/templates).